# Principle component regression using python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have strain temperature data and I have read that article
https://www.idtools.com.au/principal-component-regression-python-2/

I'm trying to build a model and predict the strain out of the temperature.

I have got the following results with cross validation is negative.

I have the data set here
http://www.mediafire.com/file/r7dg7i9dacvpl2j/curve_fitting_ahmed.xlsx/file

My question is Is it results of Cross validation makes sense ?

My code is the following

**The input is dataframe from panda.**

def pca_analysis(temperature, strain):

```
# Import the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Import Data
print("process data")
T1 = temperature['T1'].tolist()

W_A1 = strain[0]
N = len(T1)

xData = np.reshape(T1, (N, 1))
yData = np.reshape(W_A1, (N, 1))

# Define the PCA object
pca = PCA()

Xstd = StandardScaler().fit_transform(xData)

# Run PCA producing the reduced variable Xred and select the first pc components
Xreg = pca.fit_transform(Xstd)[:, :2]

''' Step 2: regression on selected principal components'''

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Fit
regr.fit(Xreg,W_A1)

# Calibration
y_c = regr.predict(Xreg)

# Cross-validation
y_cv = cross_val_predict(regr, Xreg, W_A1, cv=10)

# Calculate scores for calibration and cross-validation
score_c = r2_score(W_A1, y_c)
score_cv = r2_score(W_A1, y_cv)

# Calculate mean square error for calibration and cross validation
mse_c = mean_squared_error(W_A1, y_c)
mse_cv = mean_squared_error(W_A1, y_cv)

print(mse_c)
print(mse_cv)
print(score_c)
print(score_cv)

# Regression plot
z = np.polyfit(W_A1, y_c, 1)
with plt.style.context(('ggplot')):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))
    ax.scatter(W_A1, y_c, c='red', s = 0.4,  edgecolors='k')
    ax.plot(W_A1, z[1] + z[0] * yData, c='blue', linewidth=1)
    ax.plot(W_A1, W_A1, color='green', linewidth=1)
    plt.title('$R^{2}$ (CV): ' + str(score_cv))
    plt.xlabel('Measured $^{\circ}$Strain')
    plt.ylabel('Predicted $^{\circ}$Strain')
    plt.show()
```

Here is the result of PCR

How would I improve the prediction using that data ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKSXT.png)

Comment: Sorry, for clarity, what exactly do you mean by 'the cross validation was negative'? Cross validation the way you commented your code makes it seem like an array, which itself can't be negative.

Comment: score_cv, I meant that score

Comment: Is `score_c` also negative?

Comment: no score_c is always positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Scikit Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html), the value given by `r2_score` can be negative if your model is arbitrarily worse than random. Now, obviously this is not what one wants from using ML; you expect *better* than random results.

The first thing I would note is that your data seems like it may be quite nonlinear, in which case PCA struggles to improve model performance.

One potential substitute for PCA which accounts for essentially any nonlinearities in data is the use of autoencoders to preprocess data (Good article on these [here](http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/neural_networks/autoencoder/autoencoder.html)). They can account for nonlinearities in data if you use non-linear activation functions on some of your hidden layers of the autoencoder, which may help your model's performance. There are many articles around the web that explain this, let me know if you want some resources if you so choose to pursue this course

The next thing that I would note is that `r2_score` is really not the best way to measure error, and that using mean-squared error is much more popular, especially for linear regression. So, if you want to keep your model as simple as this, I would simply ignore the `r2_score` and move on from there. However, that being said, linear regression is *not* equipped to solve very complex problems due to its simplicity, and judging by the picture you provided, it's pretty clear to me that linear regression is very rough when applied to this dataset.

I would be interested to know the difference in mean-squared-error between the PCA and non-PCA applied data. Here, the PCA should have less error than the the normal, non-PCA applied data. If it does not, then either your data is horribly non-linear (maybe?) or there is an error in your code (I looked over it and nothing is immediately obviously wrong with it). For linear regression, mean-squared-error is really almost the unanimous error function of choice, and is remarkably effective. Hope this answers your question, leave a comment/question about my answer if you have one and I will try to clarify as best as I can.

Also, while answering your question, I cam across [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83948/is-r-squared-value-appropriate-for-comparing-models) other question that I believe explains your problem pretty well (and uses some math, so be prepared). Most notably, there are situations where R^2 error is appropriate to use for your model, but given your results, I would say that R^2 error would probably be a poor choice of error function for this data.

**Update:** Given the values that you get for the mean squared error, my first guess would be that PCA is 1) either not working bc of the nature of the data, or 2) is implemented incorrectly. While I am not an expert with the libraries you are using, I would make sure that you transform *all* of the data in the same way, i.e. make sure that the PCA transformed vectors are being compared with transformed vectors.

For moving on from linear regression, I would investigate into making a simple neural network or SVR (this might be a little trickier). Both these methods are proven to work well for complex data and are very adaptable. There tons of resources online for both of these things, and I think giving specifics on implementation of either of these methods might be out of the scope of this question (you might have to ask a separate one about this).

Comment: How would I measure mean-squared error to see it ? Can you provide sample code ?  what is an alternative to linear regression ?  Thanks so much your answer is very helpfull

Comment: Well, first notice that you already calculate the mean squared error in your code. What is the value of `mse_c` and `mse_cv` in your current program?

Comment: mse_c  0.00010744558385406445  
mse_cv 0.0001440547449662863

Comment: what is an alternative to linear regression ? that would improve the prediction ?

Comment: I have temperature over strain,  as you see in the code, I used XData as temperature and as input to PCA, is that wrong ? Should I use the strain instead ?

Comment: No, if you want to predict strain, you want PCA to be done on the temperature, so I don't think that is a problem.

Comment: can you elaborate about this ?  I would make sure that you transform all of the data in the same way, i.e. make sure that the PCA transformed vectors are being compared with transformed vectors.

Comment: The result in the above graph is ONE of the 10 sensors, I have one of the sensors that has this prediction and I think it's good ? Do you agree ? 
https://imgur.com/a/xlJIrhm

Comment: For the first comment, PCA is ultimately a transformation of the data. If you transform the data from one space to another as you do, but then compare an array/vector from one space to an array/vector from another, you are likely to get a nonsensical result (perhaps this is the cause of the negative R2 score, who knows?). I do not know the ins and outs of the `sklearn` library to know if you are doing the right thing, that might be something you want to research.

Comment: And yes, that regression looks much better than the original

Comment: So we can conclude that PCA "code" is correct, the problem is with nature of the data correct ? because some sensors has good prediction

Comment: Yea, given that you were able to get those results it is likely that PCA is working properly, and that it is the specific sensor data which makes prediction difficult.